# How does one integrate a function where the numerator is a polynomial of a degree n, and the denominator is a polynomial under root of degree m<n?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one integrate a function where the numerator is a polynomial of degree $n$, and the denominator is a polynomial under root of degree $m$ $(m<n)$?

A random example being $$\int\frac{3x^4+2x^3+3x+9}{\sqrt{2x^2 +7x+5}}\mathrm{d}x$$

I cannot do long division as the denominator is under root, and neither can I use partial fractions for the same reason. Had the numerator been of the same degree or lower, it could have been expressed as $A(denominator) + B(\frac{d}{dx}denominator) + C$ - but that can't be used here. So, what should I do? (Change the coefficients of the function if you must. I want to get the basic idea.) Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought you"d have to complete the square inside the square root, choose a suitable trig or hyperbolic substitution to dissolve the square root, and then express the numerator in terms of the new tri/hyp function. Just how easy that is to do will depend on what the numerator is....

Comment: Also, Euler substitutions provide a useful alternative to trig substitutions. The result will be a rational integrand that can be integrated via the useful methods.